# Why is my recursive definition of list_min ill-formed?

Tags: coq, beginner

I'm new to Coq and I'm on my own (self-learning).

##### Question:

> Define a function list_min that takes a list of natural numbers and returns the least element of the list.

[Source](https://cs.pomona.edu/classes/cs54/book/Structures.html#lab71)

##### My solution:

```ml
Fixpoint list_min (l : list nat) : option nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => None
  | cons h nil => Some h
  | cons h (cons h' t') => list_min (cons (min h h') t')
  end.
```

##### Coq's complain:

```
Error:
Recursive definition of list_min is ill-formed.
In environment
list_min : list nat -> option nat
l : list nat
h : nat
l0 : list nat
h' : nat
t' : list nat
Recursive call to list_min has principal argument equal to "cons (min h h') t'" instead of
one of the following variables: "l0" "t'".
Recursive definition is:
"fun l : list nat =>
 match l with
 | nil => None
 | cons h nil => Some h
 | cons h (cons h' t') => list_min (cons (min h h') t')
 end".
```

##### Questions

1. Where does `l0` come from?
2. Is there a way to inform Coq such that `(cons x y)` is shorter than `(cons (cons x y))` and thus my `list_nat` will always terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `l0` comes from the fact that deep pattern-matching such as yours (where you have two constructors) get elaborated to a succession of one-level pattern-matching. So your pattern-matching actually elaborates to something like

```
match l with
  | nil => None
  | cons h l0 =>
    match l0 with
      | nil => Some h
      | cons h' t' => list_min (cons (min h h') t')
    end
end.
```

2. There are two possibilities here: the first is to rely on tools such as [Program](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html) to give you the possibility to specify a measure showing termination. In your case, this would give something like

```
Require Import Program.

Program Fixpoint list_min (l : list nat) {measure (length l)} : option nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => None
  | cons h nil => Some h
  | cons h (cons h' t') => list_min (cons (min h h') t')
  end.
```

In general, Program generates *obligations*, corresponding to each case of your pattern-matching, where you have to show that the measure indeed decreases. But in your simple example, it is able to solve them automatically, so you do not have to do anything. If you want to look at those obligations, you can use `Obligation Tactic := idtac.` before your definition to remove the automation, and `Next Obligation` after it to look at these obligations.

2'. If you do not want to drag in Program and all its complexity, another solution is to rewrite your program in order to perform structural induction. Here is a possible solution:

```
Fixpoint list_min (l : list nat) : option nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => None
  | cons h l => match list_min l with
      | None => Some h
      | Some m => Some (min h m)
    end
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks! I came up with similar workaround as your sample solution 2'. `Program` command is beyond my knowledge right now. But I'm glad to know about it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, it is important to know that Coq does not support nested pattern matching primitively at the level of its kernel (it would be too complicated). On a definition where you match at depth 2 of a list (in the 2nd and 3rd branches) as in you question, Coq desugars the nested pattern match into a pair of pattern matches:

```ml
Fixpoint list_min (l : list nat) : option nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => None
  | cons h l0 => 
    match l0 with 
    | nil => Some h
    | cons h' t' => list_min (cons (min h h') t')
    end
  end.
```

So the `l0` that appear in the error is a trace of that desugaring operation corresponding to the intermediary list.

Now, for the second question, Coq only allows structurally decreasing fixpoints, which means that recursive calls have to happen on syntactical subterms of the main argument of your fixpoint (as precised by a `{struct t}` instruction or inferred by Coq -- in your case `l` is the main argument inferred by Coq). `cons (min h h') t'` is *not* a subterm of `l` so Coq cannot accept this recursive call.

The solutions you can consider are:

- use well founded induction on the length of your list rather than structural induction on the list (this is a generic solution, but a bit involved and it might not compute exactly the way you could expect); or
- modify your function (for instance using an accumulator for additional data) so that it is actually structurally decreasing.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that Coq does not support nested pattern matching before this